# gcc/C++: If CPU load is low, then code optimization is of little use, true?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

My colleague likes to use gcc with '-g -O0' for building production binaries because of debugging is easy if core dump happens. He says there is no need to use compiler optimization or tweak the code because he finds the process in production does not have high CPU load, e.g. 30% around.

I asked him the reason behind that and he told me: If CPU load is not high, the bottleneck must not be our code performance, and should be some IO (disk/network). So by using gcc -O2 is of no use to improve the latency and throughput. Also that also indicates we don't have much to improve in the code because CPU is not a bottleneck. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried if `-O2` binaries run faster?

Comment: Is the "30%" utilisation of a single core, or general CPU utilisation of the system running your program?

Comment: If it's not a hotspot, don't optimize it. An ugly true of life (useful not only in programming)

Comment: `if core happens` A core *dump* is something very different from a core, and the real problem is a *crash* itself. That said, it sounds like your colleague doesn't bother to search errors before releasing the program for productive use...

Comment: Does your application use multiple cores for making calculations? Do you run it on multiple-core system?

Comment: It's a multi threaded server process, serving requests and fetching data from disk/memory and then send back. I think 30% is average CPU load of all 12 cores on our box. As I said, the major reason is core dump for debugging. My colleague says throughput won't increase and latency won't decrease if CPU load is not high.

Comment: Just to elaborate on Angew's anf Algirda's point: 25% CPU load on my core i7 with four physical cores indicates CPU saturation for a single threaded application. On a 2 core system -- and it's hard to find 1 core PCs today -- 30% smoothed or averaged might include 50% bursts, i.e. a saturated core as well. Ah, I wrote that before your comment and let it sit for posterity although it doesn't apply to your case.

Comment: haven't tried -O2 yet, since my colleague is pretty sure if cpu is not 100% then no need to optimize code for less cpu usage.

Comment: @bugsking: I disagree. If CPU is not 100% then no need to hunt for a critical busy-loop bug, but 30% sustained still seems high to me (though of course it depends what you're doing and on what hardware). I certainly wouldn't write off optimisation opportunities just because I'm not literally burning silicon.

Comment: the q is, CPU load as an indicator for optimization? If load is not high, optimization can not give better latency or throughput for a server process.

Comment: @bugsking: That's not really true as there are plenty of ways to cause excess latency or low throughput in your application that have nothing to do with CPU load. Indeed, accidentally writing `sleep(1)` between each operation is going to substantially ruin your application's performance while dropping CPU load to almost zero. Whether fixing that particular bug is an "optimisation" is debateable, I concede, but I believe that are more subtle problems that are equivalent in end result but due to design problems rather than having accidentally written silly statements. :)

Comment: You are not the only citizen in a computer's user space. Be considerate. Also, core dumps should be *disabled* on production systems, for security reasons if nothing else...

Comment: @DevSolar *Also, core dumps should be disabled on production systems, for security reasons if nothing else...*  Some OSes can be configured to handle core files securely.

Comment: I would take this answer with a grain of salt. There are plenty of ways to perform optimizations in debug-friendly manner. It might be the case that the code is simply buggy, and compiler optimization make those bugs to manifest themselves.

Comment: Why bother with C++ without optimization? There are other nice languages such as Java and Python.

Answer (score 4):

### About CPU usage ~ optimisation

I would expect most optimisation problems in a program to correlate to higher-than-usual CPU load, because we say that a sub-optimal program *does* more than it theoretically needs to. But "usual" here is a complicated word. I don't think you can pick a hard value of system-wide CPU load percentage at which optimisation becomes useful.

If my program reallocates a `char` buffer in a loop, when it doesn't need to, my program might run ten times slower than it needs to, and my CPU usage may be ten times higher than it needs to be, and optimising the function may yield ten-fold increases in application performance … but the CPU usage may still only be 0.5% of the whole system capacity.

Even if we were to choose a CPU load threshold at which to begin profiling and optimising, on a general-purpose server I'd say that 30% is far too high. But it depends on the system, because if you're programming for an embedded device that only runs your program, and has been chosen and purchased because it has just enough power to run your program, then 30% could be relatively low in the grand scheme of things.

Further still, not *all* optimisation problems will indeed have anything to do with higher-than-usual CPU load. Perhaps you're just waiting in a `sleep` longer than you actually need to, causing message latency to increase but substantially *reducing* CPU usage.

**tl;dr: Your colleague's view is simplistic, and probably doesn't match reality in any useful way.**

---

### About build optimisation levels

Relating to the real crux of your question, though, it's fairly unusual to deploy a release build with all compiler optimisations turned off. Compilers are designed to emit pretty naive code at `-O0`, and to do the sort of optimisations that are pretty much "standard" in 2016 at `-O1` and `-O2`. You're generally expected to turn these on for production use, otherwise you're wasting a huge portion of a modern compiler's capability.

Many folks also tend not to use `-g` in a release build, so that the deployed binary is smaller and easier for your customers to handle. You can drop a 45MB executable to 1MB by doing this, which is no pocket change.

Does this make debugging more difficult? Yes, it can. Generally, if a bug is located, you want to receive *reproduction steps* that you can then repeat in a debug-friendly version of your application and analyse the stack trace that comes out of that.

But if the bug cannot be reproduced on demand, or it can only be reproduced in a release build, then you may have a problem. It may therefore seem reasonable to keep basic optimisations on (`-O1`) but also keep debug symbols in (`-g`); the optimisations themselves shouldn't vastly hinder your ability to analyse the core dump provided by your customer, and the debug symbols will allow you to correlate the information to source code.

That being said, you *can* have your cake and eat it too:

- Build your application with `-O2 -g`
- Copy the resulting binary
- Perform `strip` on one of those copies, to remove the debug symbols; the binaries will otherwise be identical
- Store them both forever
- Deploy the stripped version
- When you have a core dump to analyse, debug it against your original, non-stripped version

You should also have sufficient logging in your application to be able to track down most bugs without needing any of this.

Comment: The "correct" way to handle debug information on release build is to build it using `-g` and then `strip` the executable for deployment. This way it's much more certain that the debug information will match.

Comment: @skyking: True enough. In practice the two approaches _should_ yield equivalent results, because two consecutive builds with the same configuration should result in an identical binary. However, this is not rigourous, and if your program has UB (remember we're chasing a bug in this scenario) it may even not be true. I'll integrate your suggestion into my answer.

Comment: One would expect that, but no you could get different binary. There's of course the situation where you include some kind of time stamp or similar in the code. I've encountered compiler that wasn't deterministic in code generation (and that's perfectly valid behavior, but maybe unexpected).

Answer (score 2):

Under certain circumstances he could be correct, and mostly incorrect under other (while under some he's totally correct).

If you assume that you run for 1s the CPU would be busy for 0.3s and waiting for something else 0.7s. If you optimized the code and say got 100% improvement then the CPU would complete what took 0.3s in 0.15s and make the task complete in 0.85s instead of 1s (given that the wait for something else will take the same time).

However if you've got a multicore situation the CPU load is sometimes defined as the amount of processing power that's being used. So if one core runs at 100% and two are idling the CPU load would become 33% so in such a scenario 30% CPU load may be due to the program is only able to make use of one core. In that case it could improve performance drastically if the code were optimized.

Note that sometimes what is thought to be an optimization is actually an pessimization - that's why it's important to measure. I've seen a few "optimizations" that reduce performance. Also some times optimizations would alter the behavior (in particular when you "improve" the source code) so you should probably make sure it doesn't break anything by having proper tests. After doing performance measurement you should decide if it's worth trading debuggability for speed.

Comment: Unless you are writing compute-intensive algorithms, the optimization level becomes less and less important as much of the processing relies on precompiled libraries.

Answer (score 1):

A possible improvement might be to compile with `gcc -Og -g` using a recent GCC. The `-Og` optimization is debugger-friendly.

Also, you can compile with `gcc -O1 -g`; you get many (simple) optimizations, so performance is usually 90% of `-O2` (with of course some exceptions, where even `-O3` matters). And the `core` dump is usually debuggable.

And it really depends upon the kind of software and the required reliability and ease of debugging. Numerical code (HPC) is quite different from small database post-processing.

At last, using `-g3` instead of `-g` might help (e.g. `gcc -Wall -O1 -g3`)

BTW synchronization issues and deadlocks might be more likely to appear on optimized code than on non-optimized ones.

Comment: When it comes to debugging numerical HPC code, it's a pity that gdb is still missing the `--sacrifice=goat` option.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `--burn=dead-cat` ?   :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple: CPU time is not free. We like to think that it is, but it's patently false. There are all sorts of magnification effects that make every cycle count in some scenarios.

Suppose that you develop an app that runs on a million of mobile devices. Every second your code wastes is 1-2 years of *continuous* device use worth on a 4-core device. Even with 0% CPU utilization, wall time latency costs you backlight time, and that's not to be ignored with either: backlight uses about 30% of device's power.

Suppose that you develop an app that runs in a data center. Every 10% of the core that you're using is what someone else won't be using. At the end of the day, you've only got so many cores on a server, and that server has power, cooling, maintenance and amortization costs. Every 1% of CPU usage has costs that are simple to determine, and they aren't zero!

On the other hand: developer time isn't free, and every second of developer's attention requires commensurate energy and resource inputs just to keep her or him alive, fed, well and happy. Yet, in this case all the developer needs to do is flip a compiler switch. I personally don't buy the "easier debugging" myths. Modern debugging information is expressive enough to capture register use, value liveliness, code replication and such. Optimizations don't really get in the way as they did 15 years ago.

If your business has a single, underutilized server, then what the developer is doing might be OK, practically speaking. But all I see here really is an unwillingness to learn how to use the debugging tools or proper tools to begin with.

Comment: When it really matters the optimization could be PITA. The lack of optimization can leave clues behind that's useful for post mortem analyzing, the assembler code could be easier to follow.

Comment: @skyking Given that optimizations usually result in less output code (cache pressures!), and the optimization process detects and follows the patterns in the source code better, I actually find optimized assembly much easier to read.

Comment: There are numerous optimizations that can make the assembly harder to read. Instruction scheduling would often result in the assembler not following the source very well. Code sharing between functions can also make the code harder to follow.

Comment: @skyking Code sharing makes it so that you need to understand a given bit of assembly only once. Personally, I love it. Anything that decreases the quantity of assembly ending up in the executable is pretty good in my book - both for the CPU, and for a human reader.

Comment: But it doesn't follow the source code at all. Btw I don't read your book, I'm drawing from my own experience.

Comment: @skyking "my book" here stands for my experience. Oh well, our experiences differ then. I won't dispute the facts, of course. I guess the experience can go either way...